# jQuery UI tab with IE7 issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7

I am new to jQuery.

I use

```
<script src="test/lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="test/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ui_tabs/css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="test/stab_ui.js"></script>
```

and stab_ui.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#testtab').tabs();
});
```

and IE7 is giving issues with UI tabs layout on my web app.

The placement of the UI tabs overlaps the other jQuery plugin I use. I wonder if this to do with `zIndex`. If so, I need help to know where and what to modify this fix.

With other latest to date browsers Safari and FF, the UI tab displays nicely.

Where in the jQuery script that I have to modify to fix IE browser issues. I am worried that this issue may apply IE6/7/8 too.

If you need to see the problem, please let me know and I could share with you the actual look of the problem.

Thank you for your advice. Your help is **greatly** appreciated. We mean it.

Sincerely
chz

## Update

We tried using:

```
<script src="test/lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="test/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ui_tabs/css/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="test/stab_ui.js"></script>
```

and unfortunately, the layout of the jquery UI tabs still overlaps our jquery plugin treeview and pagination inside UI tab also fails in rendering. 
What else could it be? 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Definitely either need to see the problem, or you need to explain more fully what the actual problem is.

Comment: Hi Phil

Thank you so much for your response.
I just added the lines for the jquery script I use.
Do you like to see the actual problem.
I could share with you my login/password

Answer (score 3):

From a quick glance I see you're including some old CSS with new script.  jQuery UI releases updated CSS and JavaScript at the same time, they're closely tied together for many things, and upgrading one without the other is bound to cause issues.

I know from upgrading 1.7 to 1.8 recently that the 1.8 stylesheet more than a few fixes specifically for IE7 (`zoom`, primarily), ones accompanied by script changes.

Your `ui_tabs/css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css` should be upgraded to the equivalent 1.8 version, you can find a URL to to this in the top of the CSS file, assuming you haven't modified it afterwards, that link will take you to [ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) with the same color/image configuration so you can get the generated 1.8+ version.

Comment: Hi Nick

I will try your solution.
So you think this is not the zIndex issue with jquery for IE7 issue ?

Comment: @chz - The CSS including `z-index` and `zoom` properties especially get tweaked with some releases (and did with this one)...I'm not 100% sure that's your problem, but it very likely is and *definitely* is the first thing to resolve anyway, even if just to eliminate it as a possible cause.

Comment: Hi Nick
Can we share with you our login/password to let you see our issue ?

chz

Comment: @chz - I can take a quick peek, shoot me a login/url at nrcraver at gmail

Comment: Nick
You r the best, so helpful.
We tried changing to jquery-ui-1.8.custom.css but the UI tab placement is still incorrect.
We're send you the infor.

chz

Comment: Hi nick
we sent you the email.

Comment: Nick
We still can't find "To view and modify this theme, visit...." it's followed by a link to get your 1.8 CSS :) "

Comment: @chz - It's in the CSS file, exactly as I linked (removed per request).... I'm really not sure how to be any more clear than that.

Comment: We went to http://jqueryui.com/themeroller and with IE7 view source to look for  "it's followed by a link to get your 1.8 CSS". We couldn't find it in there.
Is this css in our file ?
We sincerely apologize that we get it even though it should have been obvious.

Comment: we didn't get it. ie typo above

Comment: Hi
We downloaded to use 

<script src="test/lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="test/lib/jquery-ui-1.8.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ui_tabs/css/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="test/stab_ui.js"></script> 

and unfortunately, the layout of the jquery UI tabs still overlaps our jquery plugin treeview and pagination inside UI tab also fails in rendering.

What else could it be ?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem with this jquery code, which i found on http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/

```
$(function() {
  var zIndexNumber = 1000;
  $('div').each(function() {
    $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
    zIndexNumber -= 10;
  });
});
```

I add this only for IE7 on my page